# Reverse for 'user_posts' with keyword arguments '{'username': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/by/(?P<username>[-\\w]+)/$']?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I keep getting this error in django: **NoReverseMatc**, and I can't figure out why.

**my models.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models

import misaka

from groups.models import  Group    
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts")
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   message = models.TextField()
   message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
   group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="posts",null=True, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.message

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)

   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse(
           "posts:single",
           kwargs={"username": self.user.username,"pk": self.pk})


   class Meta:
       ordering = ["-created_at"]
       unique_together = ["user", "message"]
```

**my views.py:**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.http import Http404
from django.views import generic

from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin

from . import forms
from . import models

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class PostList(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ("user", "group")


class UserPosts(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = "posts/user_post_list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            self.post_user = User.objects.prefetch_related("posts").get(
                username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        else:
            return self.post_user.posts.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["post_user"] = self.post_user
        return context


class PostDetail(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ("user", "group")

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(
            user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
        )


class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    # form_class = forms.PostForm
    fields = ('message','group')
    model = models.Post

    # def get_form_kwargs(self):
    #     kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    #     kwargs.update({"user": self.request.user})
    #     return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)


class DeletePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ("user", "group")
    success_url = reverse_lazy("posts:all")

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, "Post Deleted")
        return super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

and **my urls.py** is this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name='posts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^$", views.PostList.as_view(), name="all"),
    url(r"new/$", views.CreatePost.as_view(), name="create"),
    url(r"by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$",views.UserPosts.as_view(),name="user_posts"),
    url(r"by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$",views.PostDetail.as_view(),name="single"),
    url(r"delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$",views.DeletePost.as_view(),name="delete"),
]
```

**my _post.html**:

```html
<div class="post media">
    <h3>{{ post.message_html|safe }}</h3>
    <div class="media-body">
        <strong>{{ post.user.username }}</strong>
        <h5 class="media-heading">
            <span class="username"><a href="{% url 'posts:for_user' username=post.user.username %}">@{{ post.user.username }}</a></span>
            <time class="time"><a href="{% url 'posts:single' username=post.user.username pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.created_at }}</a></time>
            {% if post.group %}
            <span class="group-name">in <a href="#">{{ post.group.name }}</a></span>
            {% endif %}
        </h5>

        <div class="media-footer">
            {% if user.is_authenticated and post.user == user and not hide_delete %}
                <a href="{% url 'posts:delete' pk=post.pk %}" title="delete" class="btn btn-simple">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="text-danger icon-label">Delete</span>
                </a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have another application called 'questions' in my project, and it uses almost the phrases so maybe that's the problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please show the urls.py file

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "it uses almost the phrases".

Comment: Looks like something is missing here, it's having problems finding the reverse for user_posts, but I don't see any reference to user_posts in the template (only for_user and single).

Answer (score 0):

The url name that you specify in the template file is 'for_user'. This does not match with the url name that is defined in the urls.py file (name='user_posts'). These two names have to be the same for django to be able to establish a match in the urlpatterns. Also the url patterns in your code is for django 1.11 or below.

However, if you are using django 2.0 or above, use one of these two urls below;

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^by/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.UserPosts.as_view(), name='for_user'),
    path('by/<slug:username>/', views.UserPosts.as_view(), name='for_user')
]
```